# Detect every touch events without overriding dispatchTouchEvent()?

Tags: android, android-activity, touch-event

I am developing Android library which needs to track all touch events on app that uses it. For now Users should override theirs Activity’s `dispatchTouchEvent()` on their’s every activity. as shown below

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    MyLib.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But [Appsee](http://www.appsee.com/) detects touch events with `Appsee.start(“key”);` on onCreate method integrated in First activity where app starts. How is this possible. Any help??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Answering as this may be helpful to others.* Answer will be helpful for library that requires to intercept touch events.

If you dont want to overrride dispatchTouchEvent() (**Imp in case you are coding for library**) method of activity then we can use Window.Callback class. Create your own implementation of Window.Callback as code below and then set it as callback to Window object from your activity.

Do as in below code snippet for Activity context instance you get.

```
//set Window.Callback for getting touch event
        final Window win = context.getWindow();
        final Window.Callback localCallback = win.getCallback();
        win.setCallback(new MyWindowCallback(localCallback));
```

Class **MyWindowCallback** will be as :

*You will get TouchEvent on dispatchTouchEventMethod() of MyWindowCallback where you can use these as required.*

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class MyWindowCallback implements Window.Callback{

    Window.Callback localCallback;

    public MyWindowCallback(Window.Callback localCallback) {
        this.localCallback = localCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return localCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return localCallback.dispatchKeyShortcutEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //YOU WILL GET TOUCH EVENTS HERE>> USE AS REQUIRED>>
        return localCallback.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return localCallback.dispatchTrackballEvent(event);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return localCallback.dispatchGenericMotionEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        return localCallback.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreatePanelView(int featureId) {
        return localCallback.onCreatePanelView(featureId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        return localCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        boolean ret = localCallback.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        return localCallback.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        return localCallback.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowAttributesChanged(WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs) {
        localCallback.onWindowAttributesChanged(attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        localCallback.onContentChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        Log.d("","ttest onfocus changed called");
        localCallback.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        localCallback.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        localCallback.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        localCallback.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        return localCallback.onSearchRequested();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public ActionMode onWindowStartingActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        return localCallback.onWindowStartingActionMode(callback);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
        localCallback.onActionModeStarted(mode);

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
        localCallback.onActionModeFinished(mode);

    }
}
```

Comment: But how can we detect ACTION_CANCEL ?

Comment: @Adhikari In Appsee they do not pass any activity context, so how it is possible to get the same result?

Comment: Any idea on how to get info of the touched view? eg. a button's text

Comment: @MarkKWH Sorry, cannot help on that

Comment: @Pbasak Their is a way to get context without passing it, as appsee gets.

Comment: @AdhikariBishwash : How ?

Comment: @andro_abc : Ask new question for this, cannot answer in comment.

Comment: @AdhikariBishwash : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081663/detect-every-touch-events-without-getting-application-context

Comment: @AdhikariBishwash Your code is very useful, however I am not able to detect touch events on dialogs. Can you please help?

Comment: Great to find above solution for the problem. @AdhikariBishwash Can anyone help me with toast message interception in application. Similarly like touch i want to track down alerts, dialogs and toasts shown over app screen how to manage that. Any help will be usefull to me and others as well.

Comment: Thanks for this! Anyone trying to create a Unity plugin via a Fragment, you can replace `context.getWindow()` with `UnityPlayer.currentActivity.getWindow()`.