# Detect every touch events without getting Application Context?

Tags: android, android-activity

We can get Touch events for each Activity by using getWindow() on context like :

```
//set Window.Callback for getting touch event 
        final Window window = context.getWindow();
        final Window.Callback localCallback = window.getCallback();
        window.setCallback(new MyWindowCallback(localCallback));
```

How can we achieve it without using context ?

Is there any way to remove this callback (Because window class don't have any remove callback methods ?

Comment: "How can we achieved it without using context ?" - You can't, really. You could instantiate your own Window, but you'd still need a Context to do that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: how about `win.setCallback(null)` ? to remove the listener?

Comment: Applicallication crashes if you set to null. @MikeM. I think we can do : check these comments : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441531/detect-every-touch-events-without-overriding-dispatchtouchevent/25842377?noredirect=1#comment55915947_25842377

Comment: why would you want to remove callback?

Comment: Yes, but you still need a Context. If you mean you need to get a Context outside of a class that has access to one, you should explain that more clearly in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way to get Application context without passing it. I have used this code in production environment and this works fine.

```
private static Application getApplicationContext() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Context context;
    final Class<?> activityThreadClass =
            Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
    final Method method = activityThreadClass.getMethod("currentApplication");
    context = (Application) method.invoke(null, (Object[]) null);
    Log.d(tag_, "Context is " + context);
    application = (Application)context;
    return application;
}
```

Comment: And can you remove the callback ?

Comment: Just ignore callback. Don't execute your code adding conditions.

Comment: This is currently I am doing..but  i want to create one method that will remove this callback

Comment: try keeping instance of original callback using getCallback then set that callback later so your callback will not get called.

Comment: Yes..so I have set the callback...after that if i want to remove it ..is it possible ?

Comment: you cannot remove but you can replace.

Comment: I have got the solution. we can save the main window callback in our class. And next we can set it back as a callback to the main window

Comment: I was trying to say that in my previous comment. :)